# Why would you create an SQL table via a query?

Tags: sql, database-design

In most tutorials on database design, you are shown to create and manipulate tables via queries. Sorry for a newbie question but when using SQL Server Management Studio, why would you create a table using a query and not just using the built-in functions to create tables and add attributes to them? (eg: right-click\create table, go to design view and add columns and specify domains, indexes, keys etc...)

Comment: Because that's what the graphical tool does, and you get slightly more options doing it manually? Plus, it's more easily reproducible -- you can run the scripts against lots of servers, rather than having to connect to each in SSMS and click a bunch of times.

Comment: Query is the base. You have to understand queries. Tools are used to simplify by UI. But tools will also produce the query again and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks more professional to write queries in tutorials :). In real life, it's simpler to alter a table through UI, but then again, you forget the SQL syntax that way. If you're not a Database Admin, it's not that important to know SQL syntax from a-z, in my opinion.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - Scripts are not an issue, you can reproduce them easily from an existing DB.

Answer (score 4):

In any development, multiple environments are used.  Development environment is used at coding stage, then QA, then Model Office/ UAT/ Production.

Using scripts ensures that changes can be promoted automatically. It also ensures that manual errors are either eliminated or kept to a minimum.

Hand coding in each environment will be expensive and error prone. Scripts make it possible to have same table structure.

Answer (score 3):

I create tables using queries (and i store them in .sql files) because that way i can re-run them at later time to recreate the full database structure.

This sounds more useful while in a development/testing environment than it can be in productive, where i guess you wouldn't drop and re-create the entire database that often.

Comment: This I can understand but I see them also adding values into the table with an INSERT INTO sql statements. This is data input so you wouldn't need it for recreating the database structure. Why not just enter the values in Edit mode? It's like programming with Visual Studio and instead of dragging a new button from the toolbox, you would write lines of code to create the button.

Comment: I usually work with 4 script files:
-Create an empty DB
-Create tables
-Insert basic rows
-Drop DB
With these 4 scripts i can restore my database to a clean situation.
But of course, inserting and updating data using the GUI, without queries, is fully legit.
I think it's up to how many times you have to run that query.
And in my case, i run unit tests, at the start i drop the db if exists and recreate it, then i randomly (with some criteria) insert values with dynamically generated scripts. it's all about the situation, if you only have to add few rows, use the GUI, it's the best way.

Answer (score 3):

To add a reason not already mentioned - it allows the scripts to be audited / reviewed and potentially stored in a version controller or issue tracking system. This will be necessary in complex or secure scenarios especially in a fast-changing environment.